# Add class to select2 element

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

The documentation is either terrible or I'm missing something.  I'm trying to add an error class to a select2 box for form validation. It's just a 1px red border.

I found the `containerCssClass` method in the documentation, but I'm not sure how to apply it.

I have tried the following with no luck:

```
$("#myBox").select2().containerCssClass('error');
```

Comment: It would be really useful to know what on Earth `#myBox` is ?????? Is it the select object or the subsequently created select2 span elements?????

Answer (score 42, accepted):

jQuery uses JSON objects to initialize, so I guess this one will as well:\

```
$("#myBox").select2({ containerCssClass : "error" });
```

If you want to add/remove a class you can do this after you initialized it

```
$($("#myBox").select2("container")).addClass("error");
$($("#myBox").select2("container")).removeClass("error");
```

The above function gets the DOM node of the main container of select2 e.g.: `$("#myBox").select2("container")`

**Important**
You will need to use the container method to get the container since you won't edit the SELECT directly but select2 will generate other HTML to simulate a SELECT which is stylable.

Comment: Your first suggestion didn't work for me. For the second one, if you have multiple selects on the page with a single class, you need to iterate through all to add to each of them the class you need. Doing `$($(".myclass").select2("container")).addClass("error")` won't work.

Comment: Note you have to use full version:  https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/3302

Comment: I'm getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined` for the second use just for `$('#myBox').select2('container')`

Comment: If you get `Uncaught Error: No select2/compat/containerCss(…)`, you need to include the `select2.full.js` version instead of the basic one

Answer (score 39):

For already initialized select2 element I have tried @Niels solution but it resulted in an error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined`

Went into the source and this has been working instead:

```
$('#myBox').data('select2').$container.addClass('error')
$('#myBox').data('select2').$container.removeClass('error')
```

Using select2 v4.0.3 full

Comment: Thanks, your solution save my life

Comment: If you are looking for the actual element which `containerCssClass`  adds the classes to, it's `$selection` instead of `$container`.

Answer (score 24):

According to the [documentation](http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/#documentation), `containerCssClass` is only a constructor property. The best you're probably going to be able to do is reinitialize it when you get an error via:

```
$("#myBox").select2({
    containerCssClass: "error" 
});
```

**Note from comments**: If you get `Uncaught Error: No select2/compat/containerCss(…)`, you need to include the [select2.full.js](https://select2.org/getting-started/builds-and-modules) version instead of the basic one

Comment: Thanks for suggesting to add select2.full.js

Comment: @Samsquanch Where do I download the full version?  I can't seem to find it.

Comment: Nvmd, I downloaded off of Nuget which was basically legacy

Comment: Best answer, need to reference the `select2.full.js` instead of the basic one.

Answer (score 21):

For those wandering here from google, the property `containerCssClass` has a misleading name since it doesn't actually add any classes to the container element, but rather to the selection element. You can see this when you inspect the generated html.

I came across a nice little hack [here](https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/285#issuecomment-420277740) that allows you to apply your css class to the container by adding it to the `theme` property, like so:

```
$('#my-select').select2({
    theme: "bootstrap myCssClass",
});
```

Comment: If you want to keep the default class and add your custom class upon it you can try somthing like: 

`theme:"default your-custom-class"`

Answer (score 5):

use theme option.

```
 $(".select").select2({
        placeholder: "",
        allowClear: false,
        theme: "custom-option-select"
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way:

Create a parent class like

```
<div class="select-error">
    <select id="select2" name="select2" data-required class="form-control">
        <option value="" selected>No selected</option>
        <option value="1">First</option>
        <option value="2">Second</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

when you validate it with jquery or php just add style or css to .select-error class like

```
style="border:1px solid red; border-radius: 4px"
```

jQuery example:

```
$('[data-required]').each(function() {
  if (!$(this).val()) {
    if ($(this).data('select2')) {
      $('.select-error').css({
        'border': '1px solid red',
        'border-radius': '4px'
      });
    }
  });
```

Comment: While not answering the question exactly, I'm pretty sure this what the majority of viewers actually need

Comment: But what if I have 2 different selects this will also affect the second select and change it to red border

Answer (score 0):

You can use dropdownCssClass opiton

```
$("#myBox").select2({
    containerCssClass: "error" 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

select2 would make an other span with select2-container class right at the end of the body every time you click on the span tag and the dropdown with the options become visible, so you can use your click event and trigger a function that add your custom class to the dropdown container at the end of the body and also the span when there is no dropdown shown. this totaly worked for me.

```
$($(id).data('select2').$container).addClass("your-custom-class")
$($(id).data('select2').$container).click(() => $.each($("span.select2-container"), (index, value) => {
    if (index === $("span.select2-container").length - 1) {
        $(value).addClass("your-custom-class")
    }
}))
```