# How to add class to select2 element in new version 4.0?

Tags: jquery-select2

This question is the same as this one: [How to add class to select2 element in v4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30789158/how-to-add-class-to-select2-element-in-v4-0)

BUT

None of those answers work, or are correct. I thought I would ask it again because this answer is really hard to find for me.

Even in the entire select2 docs: https://select2.github.io/options.html

I cannot find anywhere about how to add a custom class to the select2 element.

Upon initialization of the select2 element, I want to add an option which will add a class to the select2 element. Simple as that but I cannot find out how.

I tried

```
containerCss: "wrap"

& 

containerCssClass: "wrap"
```

as options but they dont work.

Comment: "They don't work" is vague, and those options should do what they are meant to for the full builds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Select2 4.0 you can do it with **selectionAdapter**. Something like:

```
$.fn.select2.amd.require([
    'select2/utils',
    'select2/dropdown',
    'select2/dropdown/attachBody',
    'select2/selection/single',
    'select2/compat/containerCss',
], function (Utils, DropdownAdapter, AttachBody, SingleSelection, ContainerCss) {

  $('.my-select').select2({
    dropdownAdapter: Utils.Decorate(DropdownAdapter, AttachBody),
    selectionAdapter: Utils.Decorate(SingleSelection, ContainerCss),
    containerCssClass: 'select2-myselect'
  });
});
```

***Edit***: Or just use **`select2.full.js`** instead of **`select2.js`**

Answer (score 2):

You must use the full version of **Select2** **`select2.full.js`** in order to support the **`containerCssClass`** option.