# How can I add a class to select2 selectbox?

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I want to add the class `pink` to my select2 selectbox. It works with the option but not with the box:

```js
$("select").select2({
  templateResult: function (data, container) {
    if (data.element) {
      $(container).addClass($(data.element).attr("class"));
    }
    return data.text;
  }
});
```

```css
.yellow { background-color: yellow; }
.blue { background-color: blue }
.green { background-color: green }
.pink { background-color: pink }
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.1/css/select2.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.1/js/select2.js"></script>

<select class="select2 pink">
  <option value="AL" class="yellow">Alabama</option>
  <option value="AK" class="blue">Alaska</option>
  <option value="AZ" class="green" selected>Arizona</option>
</select>


<select class="select2">
  <option value="Something else" >Something else</option>
  <option value="Something else" >Something else</option>
  <option value="Something else">Something else</option>
</select>
```

The result I need:

[image]

Comment: should that be after selecting an option? or right away at the beginning?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao Actually I need both. I want to make a default color and after selecting I want to change the color

Comment: @guradio The class `pink` is added to the select

Comment: I found out that I need to add `containerCssClass: "pink";` somehow, but it is still not working properly

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add class to select2 element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15028995/add-class-to-select2-element)

Comment: you could easily use `$(".select2").addClass("pink")` or `$(".select2 *").addClass("pink")` is this what you want ?

Comment: @MihaiT Well, I tested this, but the background-color is not getting pink

Comment: edited my answer with a new solution. check to see if it's ok with you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why it did not work is, I used the wrong select2 version.

> It is important to integrate: select2.full.js

```js
$(".mybox").select2({
 containerCssClass: "pink",
   templateResult: function (data, container) {
    if (data.element) {
      $(container).addClass($(data.element).attr("class"));
    }
    return data.text;
  }
});
```

```css
.yellow { background-color: yellow; }
.blue { background-color: blue }
.green { background-color: green }
.pink { background-color: pink!important }
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.1/css/select2.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/select2/select2/master/dist/js/select2.full.js"></script>

<select class="select2 mybox">
  <option value="AL" class="yellow">Alabama</option>
  <option value="AK" class="blue">Alaska</option>
  <option value="AZ" class="green" selected>Arizona</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want the background-color of all options to be pink, you need to remove the standard color from the select2.css file . you can do that by using

`.select2-container--default .select2-selection--single { background:none}`

EDIT : JQ code explanation

1. store the original classes of the `.select2-container`
2. add class pink to the `.select2-container`
3. in the `on change` function , ' bring ' also the previous stored classes ( `changeMeClass` )
4. get the selected options class in `optClass` variable
5. find the `select2-container` corresponding to the selected option
6. remove all classes from the container
7. using a `setTimeout` function, add classes to the container ( original classes  + the selected option class )

let me know if this what you were looking for

see snippet below

```js
$("select").select2({
  templateResult: function(data, container) {
    if (data.element) {
      $(container).addClass($(data.element).attr("class"));
    }

    return data.text;
  }
});
var changeMeClass = $(".pink + .select2-container").attr("class")
$(".pink + .select2-container").addClass("pink")


$(".pink").on("change changeMeClass", function() {
  var optClass = $(this).children("option:selected").attr("class"),
    changeMe = $(this).next(".select2-container")

  $(changeMe).removeClass()

  setTimeout(function() {
    $(changeMe).attr("class", changeMeClass + " " + optClass)
  }, 10);





})
```

```css
.yellow { background-color: yellow; }
.blue { background-color: blue }
.green { background-color: green }
.pink { background-color: pink }
.select2-container--default .select2-selection--single { background:none!important}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.1/css/select2.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.1/js/select2.js"></script>

<select class="select2 pink">
  <option value="AL" class="yellow">Alabama</option>
  <option value="AK" class="blue">Alaska</option>
  <option value="AZ" class="green" selected>Arizona</option>
</select>


<select class="select2">
  <option value="Something else" >Something else</option>
  <option value="Something else" >Something else</option>
  <option value="Something else">Something else</option>
</select>
```

Comment: No, I need only the background color of the left select-box. And there only from the box, not the options

Comment: I posted in my question an image to demonstrate

Comment: @Jarla edited my answer with a new solution. check to see if this is what you wanted

Comment: @MihaiT, seem like drop down option was not aligned properly.