# Customize component select2

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-select2, customization

New to this forum. I hope anybody could help me with this problem. I'm using the component select2 (https://select2.org) for some input in a select. I would like to customize the select2 in two different ways in the same page.

I would like to change the font and remove the border around for one and change the font of the other.

Here's the code:

```js
$("#example1").select2({
  placeholder: "",
  selectOnClose: true
});

$("#example2").select2({
  placeholder: "",
  selectOnClose: true
});
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Using Select2</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Select2 CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/css/select2.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
  
        
    <br>
    <br>
  
      <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <label>I want font size 18 and no border</label>
          <select id="example1" class="select2">
            <option>Java</option>
            <option>Javascript</option>
            <option>PHP</option>
            <option>Visual Basic</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        
        <br>
        <br>
        
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <label>I want font size 15</label>
          <select id="example2" class="select2">
            <option>Java</option>
            <option>Javascript</option>
            <option>PHP</option>
            <option>Visual Basic</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Select2 -->
    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/js/select2.full.min.js'></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I also have created a jsfiddle with the example https://jsfiddle.net/Lfvr3m74/

Best Regards
R

Comment: A good start would be to give them both classes so you can style them with CSS. Or style them by their ID if adding classes is too much work for you.

Comment: I tried this with no luck:  #example1.select2-container .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__rendered {
    font-size: 18px;
}

Comment: `#example1.select2-container` does not exist. See my answer below.

Comment: fyi, when you use the select2 plugin, it hides the original `<select>` with that id `#example1` and then injects a bunch of `<span>`'s to make a "puesdo-dropdown" for styling purposes (since selects are notoriously un-stylable). The plugin injects this fake dropdown immediate after the original, so you can write your styles like this: `#example + .select2-container .... { }` instead of `#example.select2-container ...`. The `+` css selector selects the element immediately preceded by the former selector

Comment: also, the dropdown list itself is injected right before the closing `</body>` tag (because of overflow and stacking issues that can arise) so it is best to use the "dropdownCssClass" option and styling the list around that class. Read the options doc (here)[https://select2.org/configuration/options-api]. There is also a option for "selectionCssClass" to help style the fake dropdown input I mentioned above

Comment: Thanks Peter and zgood!! Very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your selector:

```
#example1.select2-container .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__rendered {
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

The `#example` element has no `select2-container` class. The `select2-container` is below it.

For example, you can use these selectors:

```css
span.select2-container--default .select2-selection--single {
  border: none;
}

.select2-container .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__rendered {
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

So do not use the ID of the select. Instead see this question and answer:
[Add class to select2 element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15028995/add-class-to-select2-element)